# Need to rename file path on mac for sql bulk insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, macos, operating-system

So I have two file paths, one is trying to execute like this...

`EXECUTE sys.xp_cmdshell 'dir C:\Temp\MR08X_XXX\XXX 123 ABC /b'`

The other is attempting to concatenate from this...

`CONCAT(N'BULK INSERT ', QUOTENAME(@DB), N'.', QUOTENAME(@schema), N'.', QUOTENAME(@table), N'
FROM ''C:\BCPOutput\EXPORT\', @TenantId,N'\', @FileName, N'''`

Is there a simple way I can just rename these file paths to be structured for my mac? I am fairly new to this level of SQL so I apologize in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your question, could you elaborate please? SQL Server doesn't run on a Mac (it does on Docker though), so any file paths wouldn't be pointing at your device unless you use an UNC path. But you can't be using SQl Server on Docker as you're using `xp_cmdshell`, which isn't supported on anything other than SQL Server on Windows.

Comment: I'm taking this file from a colleague, I am attempting to run it through Docker. Outside of building a new virtual machine or borrowing a PC, I wanted to see if I could run this on my machine. So I can't just rename for a Unix system?

Comment: Not with `xp_cmdshell` on Docker no, it's not supported: [Unsupported features & services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-release-notes?view=sql-server-2017#Unsupported)

Comment: Darn, thanks for the help. I will attempt this with a virtual machine.